# Yammer REST API CORS

Tags: javascript, api, rest, cors, yammer

I've setup an app in Yammer and added Javascript origins but still can't make xhr request

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.yammer.com/platform/login_status.json?client_id=123456789&_=123456789. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com.dev:9000' is therefore not allowed access.`

[image: Yammer Javascript origin setup]

Any suggestion?
I'm working from a local machine and having example.com.dev to resolve as localhost.

Comment: I could make it work somehow but Yammer API and documentation is horrible.

Comment: any hints on how you made it work? Maybe you could answer your own question.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot how I made it work-not-work, as far as I remember I deleted everything because it was always asking to authenticate and not really working. Next time I'll have to deal with Yammer I'll post here updates! Thanks for asking and sorry for not being helpful

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is in the domain name.

Use **api**.yammer.com instead of www.yammer.com

See for similar problem also the answer from Marco [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520775/yammer-cors-error-appears-only-for-some-api-calls/25523774?noredirect=1#comment39918995_25523774)

Answer (score 1):

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

You can do 2 things:

- Ask yammer.com to allow your origin, or use a non browser HTTP request, for example with cURL.
- If you develop an origin which is already allowed, then you should rewrite the hosts file and the webserver configuration on your dev machine, to bind the allowed origin to your dev site. Currently this is not an option, because there isn't any allow origin header sent according to the error message.

That's all you can do.

Comment: cURL is not an option. I'll send an email to support if I find the contact-us page :) thanks

Comment: Whoever pressed the -1, maybe you can add a comment with an explanation.

Comment: It was me, the comment wasn't and still isn't helpful. cURL is not a valid option since I'm using the Javascript SDK from Yammer. The second comment you said to rewrite hosts file. That's something I've already done and written in the question, just pay a bit more attention. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

In addition to changing the URL to be **api.yammer.com** be sure that you're not including any extra headers.

For example, I was accidentally including an extra header 'X-Foo-Id' and that was tripping up Yammer.

Answer (score -2):

Javascript origins[setting in app registration screen] needs to be updated with redirect url domain names