# Yammer CORS error appears only for some API calls

Tags: javascript, cors, yammer

When I request the data using yammer API sometimes I get hte data while sometimes I get error saying

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/topics/4990456.json?&_=1409122520954. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

When I try URL :   `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/topics/4990456.json`  to get messages for topic number 4990456, I get the above mentioned error in console log.

Similarly, when I try URL : `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/about_topic/` , I again get the above mentioned error in console log.

However, from the same page, same domain, same code, if I request `https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/my_feed.json` , I get response back.

Can someone please explain this discrepancy ? Is this the correct way to get the messages in a topic ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is in the domain name.

**www**.yammer.com and **api**.yammer.com are treated as two different domains!

I haven't tried it but I think it is a pretty safe guess that **api**.yammer.com will work for your first two requests too.

Comment: Thanks. Its stupid how I missed it. Its also mentioned in their docs (but in most ambiguous way possible).

Comment: Thanks for fielding this Erik. Nis, I work at Yammer. Can you tell me how you feel we can make the documentation more clear on this point?

Comment: @Marco If you can improve it then its great ! Your whole documentation page says to use the URL that I used (given in question) . [Ref Here](https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-messages) . If user has to use `api.yammer` then why would the API DOCS say `www.yammer` & worst part is somewhere hidden in documentation at only 1 place it is mentioned that `api.yammer` & `www.yammer` are different things which luckily I had come across but unluckily forgot.