# How to use Yammer API call without CORS?

Tags: json, api, sharepoint, cors, yammer

I'm running a Yammer Embed script on my client's Sharepoint Online tenant, which displays conversations/messages.

I am looking to create a dropdown box that can be used to filter the messages based on which Yammer groups the user is apart of.

To make the dropdown dynamic, I need to make a call to the Yammer API to get the groups of the current user - I've been using the API call:
/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1

This gives back valid JSON with correct data when browsed to directly, however when called inside the Sharepoint Online tenant I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json?mine=1. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://client.sharepoint.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

My question: Is there a way around this? I assume Yammer would need to implement CORS for this call (doubtful on getting them to do this). I've also tried the api.yammer.com/... URL to no avail.

Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yammer REST API CORS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884267/yammer-rest-api-cors)

Comment: The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884267/yammer-rest-api-cors/25568609#25568609 from the question @gotson links to above indicates you need to be using **api**.yammer.com instead of www.yammer.com. If you try that and still can’t get it working, you can fall to setting up a CORS proxy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/42744707#42744707

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [JavaScript SDK](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/js-sdk)? With that you register your JavaScript origins (where you host your custom code) on the [Client Applications](https://www.yammer.com/client_applications) page, and then use the JS SDK to handle the authentication and authorization.

Comment: Hi Brian, I am using Javascript SDK. I am getting same issue. I know, SDk is calling **api.yammer.com** and here it is **www.yammer.com**. How we can achieve this using JS SDK - or through any client side techniques?